# why $scope change the value in the whole page?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm learning AngularJS and I'm trying to make a todo app.
Everything works great except that when I'm trying to add a new todo, the previous todos changing as well.
I think it's because the `$scope` changing its value in the whole page and I want to chnage it only in the last todo which just generated.
Maybe my code would be wrong for this purpose, again, I just started learning AngularJS.

Hope you can help me out, here is my code:

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);

myApp.config(function ($routeProvider) {

    $routeProvider

    .when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'pages/main.html', 
        controller: 'mainController'
    })

    .when('/todo', {
        templateUrl: 'pages/todo.html',
        controller: 'subController'
     })

});

myApp.controller('mainController', ['$scope', function($scope){


}]);

myApp.controller('subController', ['$scope', '$compile', function($scope, $compile){

    $scope.getMsg = function(){ 

        $scope.todoHeader = $('#header').val();
        $scope.todoMsg = $('#msg').val();

        var item = $compile("<todo-item todo-Title='{{todoHeader}}' todo-message='{{ todoMsg }}'></todo-item>")($scope);
        $(".list-group").append(item);

    }
}]);

myApp.directive('todoItem', function(){
    return {
        templateUrl: 'directives/todoItem.html',
        scope: {
            todoTitle: "@",
            todoMessage: "@"
        }
    };
});
```

```html
<h3>Todo Page</h3>

<div style="margin:auto;margin-bottom: 10px;display:table;">
    <input type="text" id="header" placeholder="Enter todo header" style="margin-right:10px;padding:5px;"><br>
    <textarea type="text" id="msg" placeholder="Enter todo message" style="margin-right:10px;padding:5px;"></textarea><br>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="getMsg()">Add Todo</button>
</div>

<div class="list-group" style="margin: auto; display: table;">
</div>
```

Here is the directive (todoItem.html) code:

```js
<a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action flex-column align-items-start" style="width:600px">
<div class="d-flex w-100 justify-content-between">
    <h1 class="mb-1">{{ todoTitle }}</h1> 
</div>
<p class="mb-1">{{ todoMessage }}</p>
```

Comment: Where is the code to add ToDo's ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes indeed in your `getMsg` function you are always overriding the same `$scope` `todoHeader` and `todoMessage` variables .

And this is the default behaviour of a variable in the `$scope`, if a variable is declared in the `$scope` will be shared in the whole application, so it's changed it will affect all it's occurences in the pages.

**Solution:**

I think you should store your `todos` in an array in your scope and each time push a todo item into it, or just make the two `todoHeader` and `todoMessage` local to your `getMsg` function and use them in your new HTML todo item.

This is how would be your code:

```
//If you wanted to store the todos in an array
$scope.todos = [];

$scope.getMsg = function() {

    var todoHeader = $('#header').val();
    var todoMsg = $('#msg').val();

    //or if you want to store the todos in an array
    $scope.todos.push({
        todoHeader: todoHeader,
        todoMessage: todoMessage
    });

    var item = $compile("<todo-item todo-Title='+todoHeader+' todo-message='+todoMessage+'></todo-item>")($scope);
    $(".list-group").append(item);
}
```

Comment: It's working as you suggested, but I want to understand what values  the the todoTitle and todoMessage in the myApp.directive get?
are they the values in the attributes of todo-Title and todo-message?

Comment: They will get the last inserted values.